# Why to use *let* in functions?

Tags: clojure

I do not understand what kind of advantages or disadvantages are in using `let`, because it is possible to avoid to use let at all like in the code below?

```
(defn make-adder [x]
  (let [y x]
    (fn [z] (+ y z))))
(def add2 (make-adder 2))

;; or without let
(defn add2 [z] (+ 2 z))

(add2 4)
```

Comment: You have two things going on here - a function that generates functions, and also uses let. Your final example strips out both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most programming languages, you can declare and use *local variables* that helps you in the design of the function (or method) body. In Clojure, `let` let you *bind* local symbols to any expression that can result into a value, a data structure or another local function definition.

Your example is so simple that there is no need for the `let` construct, but you will soon encounter cases where it will be of great help for the function logic readability.

`let` is also a way to factorise code, which improve readability and performance by computing an expression only once and use the result in several places.

And, last but not least, `let` [destructuring](http://blog.brunobonacci.com/2014/11/16/clojure-complete-guide-to-destructuring/) is very convenient to produce concise code when expressions return compound structures like collections.

Answer (score 7):

There's three main reasons to name intermediate results:

1. You want to help programmers (including yourself) understand what they are, down the line.
2. You want to cache them so they can be used in multiple places without having to evaluate the expression again. This is especially important if evaluating your expression has side effects, and you only want them to happen once.
3. You're creating a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) which is going to use the `let`-ed name but not give it out to the outside world.

In your `make-adder` example, there's no real need for the `let` because it's just establishing an alias for the incoming parameter. But if you have something a bit more involved then these advantages start becoming relevant.

Just because I have it to hand, here's some code from [another recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125909/processing-a-stream-of-messages-from-a-http-server-in-clojure/30132727#30132727):

```
(defn trades-chan
  "Open the URL as a tab-separated values stream of trades. 
  Returns a core.async channel of the trades, represented as maps.
  Closes the HTTP stream on channel close!"
  [dump-url]
  (let[stream (-> dump-url
                 (client/get {:as :stream})
                 :body) ;;This is an example of 3. 
       lines  (-> stream
                 io/reader 
                 line-seq) 
       ;; This is an example of 2. I don't want to make multiple readers just because I use them in multiple expressions.

       ;;fields and transducer are examples of 1.
       fields (map keyword (str/split (first lines) #"\t")) 
       transducer (map (comp #(zipmap fields %) #(str/split % #"\t")))

       ;;output-chan is another example of 2  
       output-chan (async/chan 50 transducer)]
    (async/go-loop [my-lines (drop 1 lines)]
                   (if (async/>! output-chan (first my-lines))   
                     (recur (rest my-lines))         
                     (.close stream)))  ;;Here, the closure closes the HTTP stream, so it needs a name to refer to it by.             
    output-chan))
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not whether to use `let`, but whether to define your `add2` function directly or use a function-making-function, `make-adder`, to make it.

Your function-making-function is

```
(defn make-adder [x]
  (let [y x]
    (fn [z] (+ y z))))
```

As [@user1571406](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137692/1562315) says, the `let` does nothing useful here, and is better omitted, giving

```
(defn make-adder [x]
  (fn [z] (+ x z)))
```

... which is much easier to read. We can see that, given a number, it returns a function that adds that number to whatever it is presented with:

```
((make-adder 2) 4)
;6
```

Giving `(make-adder 2)` a name is just confusing.

Defining it explicitly, a nameless function that adds `2` is

```
(fn [z] (+ 2 z))
```

Applying it to `4`:

```
((fn [z] (+ 2 z)) 4)
;6
```