# line-seq freezes on java.io.BufferedReader in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to process an HTTP stream using clojure.

I am able to write the stream to a file, but I'm trying to process the messages using core.async.

I followed this answer here: 
[Processing a stream of messages from a http server in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125909/processing-a-stream-of-messages-from-a-http-server-in-clojure)

However when I call (line-seq ) on the  java.io.BufferedReader, it freezes for me.

```
(defn trades-stream
  []
  (let [session (new-session)
       {:keys [url sessionid]} (:stream  session)
       dump-url (str  url "?sessionid=" sessionid "&symbols=mu" )
       lines (-> dump-url
                 (client/get {:as :stream})
                 :body
                 io/reader)]
       (line-seq lines )))
```

Any idea how I would remidy this ? Thanks!

Comment: "it freezes for me." How do you know? What does it mean to freeze? What action are you taking that leads to this behavior? As written, this question contains insufficient information to understand your problem: the obvious answer is "line-seq doesn't freeze; what is the rest of your code?"

Comment: Sorry, my repl would freeze upon calling line-seq and i would need to exit and restart to be able to use it again. It happened because i was calling line-seq on a stream that was not line delineated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `line-seq` is lazy and won't do anything until forced into a string or something.  Perhaps try

```
(println (first (line-seq lines)))
```

or

```
(reduce conj [] (line-seq lines))   ; then print something
```

You can also use `(slurp  <input-stream>)` to get the contents as a string.

Comment: slurp hangs when i try that... like my repl just freezes, same thing with (println (first (line-seq lines)))

Comment: It sounds like the server is not sending out data?

Comment: it's sending XML

Comment: In fat, XML or JSON were options, but the text wasn't line delineated. 
(xml-seq)  didn't work out so well but cheshire.core/parsed-seq worked great